# Are there better Stack Exchange alternatives/clones than OSQA?

Tags: discussion

I did some research to find suitable alternatives/clones to Stack Exchange because I want to create my own self-hosted Q&A site.

The best one I found was [OSQA](http://osqa.net).
Are there **better** ones, preferably coded in PHP (as I already got some knowledge there).

Comment: Just curious, is it for a company or for a generic topic?

Comment: ...and as "the best one I found" suggests you might have found more: please at the ones you found to [Stack Overflow Clones?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [Shapado](http://shapado.com).

Comment: I wonder where they got their UI/design inspiration from?

Comment: Shapado is pretty expensive and I'd also like to self-host it.

Comment: Shapado claims to be open source, so presumably self-hosting is an option. Perhaps someone who knows the exact situation could leave an answer here.

Comment: Very nice!
I found the repository here:http://gitorious.org/shapado

Comment: @ScottMorrison, This isn't in PHP.